# disallow any letters and to ensure the first character isn't 0 regex

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

What regex should I use to disallow any letters and to ensure the first character isn't 0. I have tried the following.

```
const regex = /^[A-Za-z]/g;
const string = '0adsads123123';
const answer = string.replace(regex, '');
// Answer should be '123123'
```

Does anyone know how to do this? As you can tell regex's aren't my strongest point.

Comment: https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex.

```
^0+|[^\d]+
```

- `^0+` - Matches one or more zero at start of string.
- `|` - Alternation same as logical OR.
- `[^\d]+`  Match anything except digits one or more time.

```js
const regex = /^0+|[^\d]+/g;
const string = '0adsads123123';
const answer = string.replace(regex, '');

console.log(answer)
```